# 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'FILES'

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to update a model that contains an image field from a form as follows
in my **views.py:**

```
if request.method == "POST" and 'submit_business' in request.POST:
    id = request.POST.get('update_business')
    for object in Object.objects.filter(id=id):
        object.photo = request.FILES.get('photo')
        object.save()
```

It throws an error: `'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'FILES'`\

Comment: Please post your complete view. `request` should not be a `QueryDict` object.

Comment: Are you using POST method for submitting the form & enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form.?

Comment: yeah, I have that in my form

Comment: And, please, don't use the built-in type `object` as a variable name. And don't run with scissors.

Comment: The correct way of addressing the FILES in querydict is request.FILES['filename']. Also print the complete QueryDict on terminal to check whether you are actually POSTing any files from your HTML template or not.

Comment: @dhke am just using object as a place holder, my variable is `post_business`

Comment: @knbk my complete views is `from .models import BusinessRegistration if request.method == "POST" and 'submit_business' in request.POST: id = request.POST.get('update_business')  for object in Object.objects.filter(id=id):
    object.photo = request.FILES.get('photo')
    object.save()` other field that don't contain files are being updated in the model without problems. when I try updating a file field it throws the error

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi still not working when I replace `request.FILES.get('photo')` with `request.FILES['photo']`

Comment: What did printing the QueryDict on terminal showed you?
Also editing your question and pasting the complete views.py and the html template will help a lot.

Comment: It finally worked when I restarted the server, am using apache. Still not sure what the problem was. Thanks guys though.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error, this is how I fix it

form.resume = request.POST.FILES('resume')

to

form.resume = request.POST.get('resume')

I just changed this
[image]

into this

[image]

Comment: Don't post code as images.